# Modify value of Option selected in Select box as overflow ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, kendo-ui

I've a requirement to modify the text (Option value) overflow ellipsis in select drop down, without reflecting the ellipsis change in list.

For example,
drop down:

[image]

I want this text to be managed by overflow as ellipsis, but when I click on select to view list, then it should appear text as a whole.

FYI: I'm using Angular 6 & kendo UI for formatting templates.

I've tried multiple html/css combinations but didn't got success. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: why not use `padding-right:2rem`?

Comment: Yes, it will work to trim the text but it will not show "...".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like most operating systems cut the selected option off without an elipsis. If you were able to change how the text gets cut off, it would look strange since that’s not how select boxes work in the rest of the operating system.

If it bugs you, you can use a customizable replacement, like https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ , which looks distinct from the native select.

Comment: I know it's limitation, but I'm seeking for any hack/method to achieve it!

Comment: Hack/Method is to use customize select instead of native select box